# Cartthrob Currency Issue

Tags: cartthrob, checkout, currency

Hope your all doing well!

All the transaction on the website are charged in USD instead of CAD do I need to change something? Or Push some information in the Checkout Form?

input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value=""

[image: Cartthrob Setup Currency]

My second point I have downloaded CartThrob Multi Location Settings Manager Does it's work?

[image: CartThrob Multi Location Settings Manager]

Do I need to make something different from here?

Answer (score 1):

Check you haven't got a hidden input in your checkout form process. This can overwrite the currency. If its in there, remove it, or change the value. It usually works like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" id="currency_code" value="CAD">
```

Not sure what that add-on your using is. But the way I recently got around this was to set the location in a session, then used a Matrix field with the "Country" choice on each row.

I made it also pull the "Country" from ones I had set inside Low Variables so the client could add different countries whenever they wanted.